# Getting multiple VOP_OPEN() and VOP_CLOSE() calls from kernel when trying to copy a file into my VFS on OSX versions 10.9+

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, kernel-module, vfs, kernel-extension

When a file is copied into my VFS, I get multiple `VOP_OPEN()` and `VOP_CLOSE()` in my Kernel Extension module from OSX (version 10.9+) Kernel. This sort of behavior was not seen on OSX versions earlier to Mavericks. 
I used call to `VOP_CLOSE()` in kext as a event to trigger check-in to server as this was called only after a file is completely copied in earlier versions. Now with multiple calls to Open and close vnode while file is still being copied, I never really know when file has been copied completely.
How do I get around this issue?